# How to export data from autodesk into excel

Tags: automation, autodesk-viewer, autocad

Hello I am recently a new hire at a controls company tasked with autogenerating check sheets from Autocad drawings. What is the best way to go about this? is there an export in Autodesk where I can get conveyor numbers? The Check sheet would look something like this [image: Checklist image] so as of now I am only concerned with getting conveyor number and order out of the drawings.

I have tried to get it from the drawings itself however I'm not really sure how to write computer vision tools and get them into excel so some kind of export I think is my best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the services in Autodesk Platform Services - [Model Derivative service](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/) - can be used to extract all sorts of information from your CAD designs. Information such as:

- 2D drawings,
- 3D views,
- logical hierarchies,
- design element metadata, etc.

All this data can then be retrieved from Model Derivative APIs in the JSON format. I believe you should be able to get the data you need this way.

Comment: And if this approach does _not_ extract the data you need, you could consider using the [Design Automation service](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) instead. This service allows you to execute your custom AutoCAD (or Revit, Inventor, etc.) plugins in the cloud. Your custom AutoCAD plugin could then extract the data you need.

Comment: Thanks so much I was looking through the code samples and noticed the excel one now gives a 404 error, is this no longer possible or a sample that they have given up on?

Comment: Which sample exactly are you referring to Jared? Btw here's one of our github code samples that might be of interest: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extract-spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes I believe this is the one I was trying to reach. on This page the link gives you a github 404 error on the very bottom github link. https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/code_samples/code_samples/